# Is it possible to change systemd private tmp directory?

Tags: systemd, tmp

I am running some programs on both Debian and Fedora. When I `ls` the `/tmp` directory, I see many directories with extremely long name like

```
systemd-private-d85027...-bluetooth.service-qxzMGm
systemd-private-d85027...-chronyd.service-vSzXdP
systemd-private-d85027...-colord.service-LvpIL2
systemd-private-d85027...-fwupd.service-cbpodH
systemd-private-d85027...-httpd.service-rJIaIX
```

It seems to be related to PrivateTmp, but how can I remove them or move them to a less distracting location? (e.g. from `/tmp/systemd-...` to `/tmp/.systemd-...`) I want to try not to change the PrivateTmp option for every service.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to do that... There's reasons for that to be under /tmp or /var/tmp (e.g. preserving the SELinux context)... The names are currently hardcoded in systemd, not sure they're going to change... I guess my advice here is to avoid using /tmp for things you want to find later using `ls`? Not sure what's your particular use case (or if you can avoid /tmp), anyways, leaving a comment in hopes it might be helpful...

Comment: As filbranden says, you should probably avoid using `/tmp` for your files.  Check to see if `$TMPDIR` or `$TMP` are set (or set them yourself) and use one of them.  I generally use `$TMPDIR` if defined, then `$TMP` if defined, then fall back to `/tmp`