# decluttering systemd-private clutter?

Tags: systemd, tmp

Is there any way to configure systemd so that it creates its private tmp directories (for unit files with `PrivateTmp=true`) in subdirectories under /tmp and /var/tmp instead of the top-level of those directories?

e.g. it currently creates them like this:

```
# ls -ld /tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-*/* /var/tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-*/*
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 6 Sep 16 15:55 /tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-ntp.service-cZ4bQf/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 6 Sep 16 15:55 /tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-systemd-logind.service-E8cjtf/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 6 Sep 16 15:55 /var/tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-ntp.service-015lsf/tmp
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root 6 Sep 16 15:55 /var/tmp/systemd-private-b8dba43636ff40c587b44e11317c96f8-systemd-logind.service-7bToCf/tmp
```

i.e. they're just a bunch of .../tmp/ directories with 1777 permissions.

I want these created under /tmp/systemd and /var/tmp/systemd so that they don't clutter my /tmp and /var/tmp directories with annoyingly long and ugly directory names.

why? so that I can see what's in /tmp/ in only one screenful on a 25x80 terminal. I want them out of the way, out of sight, out of mind.

Is this configurable in systemd?  I can't find any mention of it in any of the systemd man pages or online docs I've looked at.

Comment: The base paths used by systemd are hardcoded, so this isn't currently configurable.  (The reason is to maintain invariants such as SELinux's security setting for "/tmp/*", which would silently break if a bunch of temporary files suddenly moved to /somewhere/else.)  I would be a big fan of providing some kind of additional path to the base path, so that `PrivateTmp=true` and `PrivateTmpExampleMorePath=whatever` created all this noise under `/tmp/whatever` instead.

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435367/is-it-possible-to-change-systemd-private-tmp-directory